# How can I convert my output in neat data table so that I can export that to my word document?

Tags: r, datatable

Below is my output of phillip perron test> I want this as a table with 2 columns: 1) variable names and 2) p-value at level. Can someone please help me with this. I am a noob and need help with how to convert such data outputs in neat and presentable form so that I can put them in my word document

```
 $exp

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -5.9809, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.01


$`log(ER_USD)`

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -1.5405, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.768


$LSM

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -2.2738, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.4622


$EFSspread

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -1.6376, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.7275


$psc

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -1.4049, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.8245


$`log(cpi)`

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -2.0289, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.5643


$oil

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -2.8521, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.221


$cop

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -1.0216, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.932


$imports

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  X[[i]]
Dickey-Fuller = -5.3708, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.01
```

Comment: Check out the broom package. That might work for you

Comment: It would be much more helpful (and you may get more responses) to provide an example of your data and describe what you want rather than to provide the output.

Comment: I have run a var model using VAR function of vars package. Now before running var I had to check for stationarity(above output). Once done with stationarity tests, I ran a var model on my data and got output using stargazer. Stargazer has a feature of converting output into latex but I need to put my output in word.